# How to partially mock a typesafe function with jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I have a typescript application. I am using `jest` to mock a `NestFactory` class's `create` function.

Normally, `create` function returns an `INestApplication` which contains like 20+ methods/properties. I am just interested in one of them named as `listen`.

I want to mock `create` method to return a mocked `listen` so I can use that mocked `listen` to test stuff.

I can't manage to do that without breaking the type safety.

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';

// Here is the automatic jest mock
jest.mock('@nestjs/core');

// I get mocked NestFactory here with all the type safety.
const mockedNestFactory = jest.mocked(NestFactory);

test('', () => {
  // This is the mocked listen function I want `create` method to return it so I can use it to test some stuff.
  const mockedListen = jest.fn();

  // Here I try to mock create function's implementation and make it return my mocked listen.
  // Of course I get a type error here because my mocked returned object only contains listen and does not contain other 20+ methods/properties that INestApplication contains
  mockedNestFactory.create.mockResolvedValue({
    listen: mockedListen,
  });
});
```

As a solution to this, I can just typecast to `any` which will break all the type safety and I have to manually check mock and actual `NestFactory` API matches all the time. So I don't want to do it.

How can I mock the `create` function so it returns a mocked `listen` while keeping it type safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't find an easy solution that does not require extra packages.

So, I end up using `jest-mock-extended` It can create a mock object from an `interface`.

Here is the usage

```
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { mock } from 'jest-mock-extended';

const mockedNestApplication = mock<INestApplication>();
jest.mocked(NestFactory).create.mockResolvedValue(mockedNestApplication);
```

Here, with the help of `jest-mock-extended`'s `mock` function. I create a mock object from required `interface`, `INestApplication`.

By using that, I provide a `mockResolvedValue` to `create` method.

I can test `listen` method as I like.

```
expect(mockedNestApplication.listen).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
```

With that,

- I prevent using `as any` or `as unknown as INestApplication`. They cause fragile mocks and not type safe.
- No need to manually implement all the properties in the interface.